# ESP8266 NonOS fails to connect to WiFi network hosted by other ESP8266

Tags: c, esp8266, esp8266wifi

I am trying to connect a ESP8266 to a WiFi network hosted by another ESP8266. The problem is the ESP8266 shows the WiFi network during a WiFi scan but fails to connect to it with the error: `no espnetwork found, reconnect after 1s`.

Code for the ESP8266 hosting the network:

```c
#include <osapi.h>
#include <user_interface.h>

void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR user_init(void) {
    // Delays 1 second for my serial monitor to catch up
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) os_delay_us(5000);

    gpio_init();
    uart_init(115200, 115200);

    wifi_softap_dhcps_stop();

    wifi_set_opmode(SOFTAP_MODE);

    struct softap_config softAPConfig = {
        .ssid = {0},
        .password = {0},
        .ssid_len = sizeof("espnetwork"),
        .authmode = AUTH_OPEN,
        .max_connection = 4,
        .beacon_interval = 100,
    };

    os_memcpy(softAPConfig.ssid, "espnetwork", sizeof("espnetwork"));

    wifi_softap_set_config(&softAPConfig);

    wifi_softap_dhcps_start();
}

uint32 ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR user_rf_cal_sector_set(void) {
    enum flash_size_map size_map = system_get_flash_size_map();
    uint32 rf_cal_sec = 0;

    switch (size_map) {
        case FLASH_SIZE_4M_MAP_256_256:
            rf_cal_sec = 128 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_8M_MAP_512_512:
            rf_cal_sec = 256 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_16M_MAP_512_512:
        case FLASH_SIZE_16M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 512 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_32M_MAP_512_512:
        case FLASH_SIZE_32M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 1024 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_64M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 2048 - 5;
            break;
        case FLASH_SIZE_128M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 4096 - 5;
            break;
        default:
            rf_cal_sec = 0;
            break;
    }
    return rf_cal_sec;
}
```

Code for the ESP8266 searching and connection to the network:

```c
#include <osapi.h>
#include <user_interface.h>

static os_timer_t INIT_TIMER;

void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR commScanCb(void *arg, STATUS status) {
    if (status != OK) return (void)os_printf("Scan Callback Error : %d", status);

    struct bss_info *scanInfo = (struct bss_info *)arg;
    struct bss_info *network  = NULL;

    while (scanInfo != NULL) {
        if (!os_strcmp(scanInfo->ssid, "espnetwork")) network = scanInfo;

        scanInfo = STAILQ_NEXT(scanInfo, next);
    }

    if (network == NULL) return (void)os_printf("Network Not Found");
    else os_printf("Found Network : %s\n", network->ssid);

    struct station_config config = { .bssid_set = 0 };

    os_memset(config.ssid, 0, 32);
    os_memcpy(config.ssid, network->ssid, 32);

    wifi_station_set_config(&config);

    wifi_station_connect() ? os_printf("WiFi Connect Started\n") : os_printf("WiFi Connect Failed\n");
}

void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR afterInit(void *arg) {
    os_timer_disarm(&INIT_TIMER);

    wifi_station_scan(NULL, commScanCb);
}

void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR user_init(void) {
    // Delays 1 second for my serial monitor to catch up
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) os_delay_us(5000);

    gpio_init();
    uart_init(115200, 115200);
    
    wifi_station_set_auto_connect(0);

    wifi_set_opmode(STATION_MODE);

    os_timer_disarm(&INIT_TIMER);
    os_timer_setfn(&INIT_TIMER, (os_timer_func_t *)afterInit, NULL);
    os_timer_arm(&INIT_TIMER, 1000, 1);
}

uint32 ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR user_rf_cal_sector_set(void) {
    enum flash_size_map size_map = system_get_flash_size_map();
    uint32 rf_cal_sec = 0;

    switch (size_map) {
        case FLASH_SIZE_4M_MAP_256_256:
            rf_cal_sec = 128 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_8M_MAP_512_512:
            rf_cal_sec = 256 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_16M_MAP_512_512:
        case FLASH_SIZE_16M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 512 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_32M_MAP_512_512:
        case FLASH_SIZE_32M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 1024 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_64M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 2048 - 5;
            break;
        case FLASH_SIZE_128M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 4096 - 5;
            break;
        default:
            rf_cal_sec = 0;
            break;
    }
    return rf_cal_sec;
}
```

Log from the ESP8266 trying to connect to the network:

```
mode : sta(5c:cf:7f:f6:54:cb)
add if0
scandone
Found Network : espnetwork
WiFi Connect Started
scandone
no espnetwork found, reconnect after 1s
reconnect
scandone
no espnetwork found, reconnect after 1s
reconnect
scandone
no espnetwork found, reconnect after 1s
reconnect
```

This log shows that the ESP8266 finds the network (line 4) but then fails to connect and then indefinitely tries to reconnect.

I have tried to change the auth mode of the WiFi network and give it a password, I have also tried setting `bssid_set` to 1 and passing in the bssid of the WiFi network but in both cases the same error arises.

Comment: STATIONAP acts as an access point AND joins an existing network.  You don't have the existing network.  I think you want one in SOFTAP and the other in STATION mode.

Comment: @stark I know. I would like to expand the network with more ESP8266s into a mesh, so all need to be able to host a softap and be a station. To test I tried making one only a softap and the other only a station but the station still receives the same error.

Comment: @stark I was trying to connect the ESP8266s together, so I swapped the CURRENT_SSID and OTHER_SSID when uploading to each ESP8266. Then I powered on the first which would host a softap and not find the other ESP8266. After I powered on the second which should host a softap and then find the other and connect to it but it gives the error.

Comment: @stark I have added more context. Sorry I didn't put many details in at the start.

Comment: I suggest you look into ESP-NOW instead of using classical WiFi for your setup: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp-now-esp8266-nodemcu-arduino-ide/

Comment: @MarcelStör I have looked into ESP-NOW but I would like to use WiFi networks. I have rewrote my question and made it more concise on the problem.

Comment: I might be misreading (and have never touched this platform), but it looks like you aren't setting `softAPConfig.ssid` to your SSID. Is that a copying error?

Comment: @Hasturkun Good spot, I did forget to add that but the SSID was already saved in the flash from other runs. So sadly that is not the problem.

Comment: @Gus Can you try out the example [here](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/2c-esp8266_non_os_sdk_api_reference_en.pdf) so we can narrow down if it's a STA problem or an AP problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the SoftAP code. When setting the `softap_config` I used sizeof instead of strlen or not setting it at all, leading it to host a network with a null char in the SSID.

Fixed Example:

```
#include <osapi.h>
#include <user_interface.h>

void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR user_init(void) {
    // Delays 1 second for my serial monitor to catch up
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) os_delay_us(5000);

    gpio_init();
    uart_init(115200, 115200);

    wifi_softap_dhcps_stop();

    wifi_set_opmode(SOFTAP_MODE);

    struct softap_config softAPConfig = {
        .ssid = {0},
        .password = {0},
        .authmode = AUTH_OPEN,
        .max_connection = 4,
        .beacon_interval = 100,
    };

    os_memcpy(softAPConfig.ssid, "espnetwork", sizeof("espnetwork"));

    wifi_softap_set_config(&softAPConfig);

    wifi_softap_dhcps_start();
}

uint32 ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR user_rf_cal_sector_set(void) {
    enum flash_size_map size_map = system_get_flash_size_map();
    uint32 rf_cal_sec = 0;

    switch (size_map) {
        case FLASH_SIZE_4M_MAP_256_256:
            rf_cal_sec = 128 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_8M_MAP_512_512:
            rf_cal_sec = 256 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_16M_MAP_512_512:
        case FLASH_SIZE_16M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 512 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_32M_MAP_512_512:
        case FLASH_SIZE_32M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 1024 - 5;
            break;

        case FLASH_SIZE_64M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 2048 - 5;
            break;
        case FLASH_SIZE_128M_MAP_1024_1024:
            rf_cal_sec = 4096 - 5;
            break;
        default:
            rf_cal_sec = 0;
            break;
    }
    return rf_cal_sec;
}
```

Thank you for all the help.